# How to add different page number on the same page in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-office

I need to add page number say 1 in the header section and +1 i.e. 2 in the footer section on the same page.

say for first page.

Header-- "page 01"

Footer-- "running page 02"

How to do this?

I am using ms word 2007(32 bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slightly tricky problem that will not be solved by any amount of R&D in the header & footer area. Here we will use what is known as 'Field codes'.

In the header area, add the Page No. as you normally would do i.e by selecting Insert > Header & Footer Section > Page Number > Choose Top of the page. This will be our original Page No. Once you insert the page No., you can edit the language by double clicking on Header and adding your heading like **"Page No** etc before the No.

The tricky part comes in the Footer area. Select the footer area and place the curser anywhere inside it.

Press **Ctrl+F9** . You will get one pair of curly bracket like this: **{ }**

Again press **Ctrl+F9** once more. You will get the another curly bracket and the screen will look like this: **{ { } }**

Now the formula part: Fill the characters inside these curly brackets so that the final figure looks like this:-

**{={PAGE}+1}**

See the enclosed image if it not clear : [Formula in large font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM6ff.jpg)

Now press the Key **Alt+F9** together.

You will see that whereas in the header, the page no. is 1, in the footer part, the page no. has become as 2.

Again press Ctrl+F9 to make the formula visible again. Type the 'whatever sentence you want before the formula like "Running Page" etc.

Again press the key Alt+F9 to see the result. Final product will be like this image : [final look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iphkb.jpg)

**Please remember**: You can't simply type the curly brackets. That way, they will be just part of the language.  You will have to insert them using the Ctrl+F9 keys so that they retain their field code quality.

**Alt+F9** : for viewing the results.

**Ctrl+F9** : for toggling to view and edit the brackets mode.

Hope it will help.

Comment: `Please remember: You can't simply type the curly brackets. That way, they will be just part of the language. You will have to insert them using the Ctrl+F9 keys so that they retain their field code quality.` I found this code and got syntax error. I think the reason is manual input. Thank you. Let me check it later using Ctrl+F9.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Ctrl+F9 did the trick. T's notorious design of Microsoft!!